# How do I set up Visual Studio 2022 to highlight javascript in Razor view and also not show me errors where they aren't?

Tags: .net-core, intellisense, syntax-highlighting, razor-pages, visual-studio-2022

I have been working in VS 2019 since 2018 and now I wanted to switch to VS 2022.

However I have several problems with it:

1. It doesn't highlight and use Intellisense in Javascript.
2. I have many warnings from stuff that is perfectly normal. Like here in the bootstrap file:
   [image: Bootstrap file error]
3. In my CSS block inside the Razor view, I have this which also throws a warning "CSS102   "src" is not a known CSS property name.":
   [image: CSS error]

Can I somehow make VS22 work exactly the same as VS19? It is much faster I've found out in my use case and I like how it looks more (I know, stupid. But I look at the damn program all day every day.)

THANK YOU!

Comment: Issues 2 and 3 are a bug, I've filed one here to track it: https://github.com/dotnet/razor-tooling/issues/6085

Comment: @Jimmy Thanks. I will wait for an update, then!